# TelegramBot is not working (Spring Boot, telegrambots)

Tags: java, spring-boot, telegram-bot

Recently I started writing my first telegram bot using Java 17, Spring boot and telegrambots-spring-boot-starter. My bot was registered via BotFather in Telegram correctly. Now, my but do nothing and breakpoints doesn't work at all (it seems that my java program is not receiving any command from bot).

## My BotController class

```
package com.menkov.klim.weatherforecasttelegrambot.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

@Component
public class BotController extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @lombok.Getter
    @Value("${telegram.bot.username}")
    private String botUsername;

    @lombok.Getter
    @Value("${telegram.bot.token}")
    private String botToken;

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        try {
            String chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId().toString();

            SendMessage message = new SendMessage();
            message.setChatId(chatId);
            message.setText("Hi!");

            execute(message);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## My POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.menkov.klim</groupId>
    <artifactId>WeatherForecastTelegramBot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WeatherForecastTelegramBot</name>
    <description>WeatherForecastTelegramBot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

## My main class

```
package com.menkov.klim.weatherforecasttelegrambot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.menkov.klim.weatherforecasttelegrambot.controller"
})
public class WeatherForecastTelegramBotApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WeatherForecastTelegramBotApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I`ve changed POM dependencies versions but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

you should start your code with this:

```
@EventListener({ContextRefreshedEvent.class})
public void init() throws TelegramApiException {
    TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
    try {
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(this);
    }
    catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        log.error("Error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must register your bot:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WeatherForecastTelegramBotApplication.class, args);
        try {
            TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
            botsApi.registerBot(new BotController());
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not look particularly different from @Sam's answer.

Comment: Same way but main method. @daniu

Answer (score -1):

I`ve found the issue.
The problem was in package-scanning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).